# what is the Best way to use es6 with rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ecmascript-6

What is the best way to use ES6 with rails asset pipeline?. I am trying to write some es6 syntax in my angular-rails application, which uses the rails asset pipeline. The code actually works in local but throws a syntax error when trying to deploy(digital ocean). [image: Stack Trace]

This is error I am getting while I am deploying. And the code I am trying to run is

```
class Hello {
 constructor() {
 alert('Hello!');
 }
}

new Hello();
```

Comment: The code doesn't work because you did something wrong. Fix what is wrong and it will work.

Comment: I just added a let variable which is es6 syntax

Comment: You might be interested with webpacker: https://github.com/rails/webpacker

Comment: paste the stack trace of error

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 11):

Current uglifier version doesn't support ES6, It is on experimental mode hence you will need to manually enable ES6 compiling.

You will need latest uglifier gem version.

ES6 support can be enabled with `:harmony => true` option while setting js_compressor in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(
    # ES6 support
    :harmony => true
)
```

[Check here official docs](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier)

Hope it helps